# Synthesis ToolKit with Xcode

Tags: c++, synthesis

I'm trying to build the a project using STK with xcode. I added all the STK's files (.cpp and .h) in my project folder, I added the pthread, CoreAudio, CoreMidi and CoreFoundation Frameworks (Build phases, Link Binary with Libraries) and the preprocessor macro `__MACOSX_CORE__` in the Build Settings menu. There is no syntax error, but it doesn't link (Undefined symbols for architecture...). I can't figure out what i did wrong. Can someone help me ? I'm trying to compile the code given in the STK official tutorial.
Thank you

Comment: I have the same trouble here...

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial and it works fine: http://arielelkin.github.io/articles/mandolin. Maybe you can trace the steps in the tutorial and match the steps to yours manually. Hope that helps.